# Recently taken camera image won't display on Ionic page

Tags: html, typescript, ionic-framework

I am trying to display two images on a page using Ionic. I am taking one photo via a camera, and I am pulling the other image down from the web. I can successfully store the images as a `FILE_URI` that is something like the following:

Camera:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A696490-1D2B-4A22-B058-8F814AF52D90/tmp/cdv_photo_001.jpg
```

Web:

```
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/2A696490-1D2B-4A22-B058-8F814AF52D90/Documents/file.png
```

The problem arises when I try to view the files. When I try to set an `img` HTMLElement's `src` in typescript via `document["img1"].src = this.cameraImageURI;` I get an error on my xcode console that is the following:

```
ERROR: Unable to send exception to server [object Object]
```

My page never even loads because of this error. I believe my issue may be with passing the entire string (as shared above) into the `img1` `src` attribute.

I have looked into Ionic's [`FileOpener` class](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/), but I am not sure if that is the way to go.

**UPDATE 1:** I tried slicing out the file://, but unfortunately, that didn't work. Also, I tried using their function, `normalizeURL`, which should solve the issue too. The documentation for this is found [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/). But alas, it makes the string:

```
http://localhost:8080/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application‌​/17737D0A-F9C2-4DD9-‌​8A9B-4DA6A094D100/tm‌​p/cdv_photo_001.jpg
```

which didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using WkWebView? If so you should maybe tro to rewrite your URL aka remove 'file://'. See https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/ topic "Rewriting file://"

Comment: Thank you for that webpage. I tried slicing out the `file://`, but unfortunately, that didn't work. Also, I tried using their function, `normalizeURL`, which should solve the issue too, but it makes the string `http://localhost:8080/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/17737D0A-F9C2-4DD9-8A9B-4DA6A094D100/tmp/cdv_photo_001.jpg` which didn't work either.

Comment: Freak :( Maybe something with the HTMLElement. Could you try without it, like `<div *ngIf="cameraImageURI != null"><img [src]="cameraImageURI"></div>` ps.: I'm assuming that `cameraImageURI` is a public variable of the class/view/page

Comment: Awesome! :) That worked! What exactly is this doing?

Comment: It just render the image when the url is loaded, not before. But I'm more guessing that there was a problem with using `document`. Anyway good to hear it worked out!!! Would you like to post the answer and mark the question as solved or should I?

Comment: I would be happy to give you the points if you want to post your answer :)

Comment: Hahaha ok I do it right now then, thx ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments above, firstly we figured out that the first problem was linked with `WkWebView` not supporting URI containing `file://`.

To remove it, Ionic provide an handy util method which could be use as follow:

```
import { normalizeURL } from 'ionic-angular';

this.cameraImageURI = normalizeURL(this.cameraImageURI);
```

Dokumentation could be found at https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/ see topic "Rewriting file://

Secondly I thought that OP might had a problem with setting the URI result with `document`. I suggested to access the URI from the page template as following and luckily it worked out ;)

```
<div *ngIf="cameraImageURI != null">
  <img [src]="cameraImageURI">
</div>
```

Note: Doing so, the image will be only rendered if the URI isn't empty. Furthermore, `cameraImageURI` has to be a public variable of the class/view